# Printing a Map with a nested Map

Tags: java, arrays, collections, printing, hashmap

I have a Map of the following kind:
`HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();`

Where `String(Key) = Website address;`

```
Map<String,Integer> = String(key) -search word, Integer(value) - counter for found words.
```

How to print the Map correctly so that it looks like this:

1. webSite1 - randomWord = 30, randomWord2 = 15, randomWord3 = 0
2. webSite2 - randomWord = 9, randomWord2 = 8, randomWord3 = 1

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What causes the problem for you?

Comment: I do not understand how to retrieve data from the resulting Map via foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` has simple iterator `forEach((key, value) -> your_consumer)`, and the entries in the nested map may be converted into strings joined using `Collectors.joining`, so printing may be done as follows:

```
resultMap.forEach((k, v) ->
    System.out.println(k + " - " + 
        v.entrySet().stream()
         .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
         .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood you:
In the outer loop, you should iterate the nested maps (as values),
and in the internal loop(s) you can finally iterate keys and values of the nested map.

```
HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map<String, Integer> nestedMap : map.values()) 
        {
            for (String key : nestedMap.keySet()) {
                // some actions here
            }
            
            for (Integer value : nestedMap.values()) {
                // some actions here
            }
        }
```